# Integrating facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I am hoping to use Facebook to log into my application. The user is given 2 options, either he/she could log in using FB or else by registering with the system and login in to the application.

I browsed through the FB Graph API, and downloaded there sample application. It showed how to post a note to my wall. SO when i click on the Facebook button, i sign-in and then the page gets re-directed to the post-to wall view.

What i want to do is, to only Login to Facebook (Not Post to Wall). Is this possible ? Is there any tutorial or sample code which would help me do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) provides a method called [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) that will do what you want.

Comment: Hve you checked out their ios SDK?  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/

It has a built in login method that calls into the Facebook iPhone app if it's installed, or the web browser.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/), specifically the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/authentication/) section, for a native iOS app.